# Function returning true and false in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, validation

I am making a simple validation function that just validates that the props given to the component are not null. When the function runs it gets to the last conditional and logs 'made it' but then also logs '1' which is the else for the first conditional and returns false. I am not sure why its getting to the last conditional and its not returning true. I have also tried using else if statements.

```
         function testValidation(firstOptionWords, secondOptionWords, chooseFirst,  chooseSecond) {

      if(props.enabled) {



        if(firstOptionWords && secondOptionWords) return true; 

          if(firstOptionWords.length > 0 && secondOptionWords.length > 0) return true;

            if(chooseFirst != null && chooseSecond != null) return true;
            return false;
          }

       else {

        console.log('Choice is false!')
      }
     }

     const speechRecognizing = async (firstOptionWords, secondOptionWords, chooseFirst,  chooseSecond) => {

      const results = partialResults.map(function (x) {return x.toLowerCase()});
      const matched1 =  firstOptionWords.some(options => results.includes(options));
      const matched2 =  secondOptionWords.some(options => results.includes(options)); 
      const matchedWildCard = partialResults.length > 0 && firstOptionWords.includes('\*');

      try {
            if(testValidation()) {

              await Voice.isRecognizing();

              const voiceIsRecognizing = await Voice.isRecognizing();
              
                  // TODO run checklists and clean up code, and comment where nessecary. Make sure that all promises are resolved and the library functionality is to design spec.
                  if(voiceIsRecognizing) { 

                      if(matched1 || matchedWildCard) {
                          
                          
                          chooseFirst();
                          stopAndDestroy();
                          
          
                      } else if (matched2) {

                         
          
                        chooseSecond();
                        stopAndDestroy();
          
                      } else {
                          
                          stopAndDestroy();
                      }
                    
  
                  } else {
                      
                      console.log('STARTING');
                      startRecognizing();
                  
                  }

            } else {

              console.log('Validation did not pass')
            } 
      } catch (error) {
          
          console.log(error);
      }
  }

  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    testValidation(props.firstOptionWords, props.secondOptionWords, props.chooseFirst, props.chooseSecond); 
    speechRecognizing(props.firstOptionWords, props.secondOptionWords, props.chooseFirst, props.chooseSecond);
      
      
      }, [partialResults, props.enabled]);
```

Comment: When you are calling this function?

Comment: Probably is called twice with different input

Comment: Unrelated, but IMO this would be much easier to read and understand if it was modeled as a series of guard clauses that returned early.

Comment: Yes, the logic seems to be OK in the function. So, @javaluca's assumption seems likely.

Comment: I hae the function in a useEffect() and the function gets called twice once props.enabled becomes true.  Could someone possibly post an example code of a guard clause for this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I am also intrigued on how it would get called with different input if the information getting passed is the same.

Comment: I have updated the above code example to include a guard clause and how I am using it fully in the app. For some reason its still not passing.